# Any application crashes on ios 5.1.1 whith xcode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, ios-simulator

Every application that works on simulator crashes on my device at the very beginning. Even if it's just a blank app. And the xcode doesn't stop debugging and doesn't show any log. I dont have a developer id so i just bypassed the code signature but i don't think it's caused by that. Tried out different build settings but nothing helped...

Comment: That is far to vague to get an answer I guess

Answer (score 3):

You can't just bypass the code signature, It won't run. 
What you're seeing is not a crash, but the device closing the app.

You need a valid Developer ID, and the necessary certificates to be able to test on a device.

You however do not need a valid Developer ID to test/run in the simulator.